# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains'::

Tags: spring, spring-security, jakarta-migration

I am using Spring instead of Jakarta EE and deployed on Glassfish 6 (RI implementation for Jakarta EE 9 ). I have updated the version of spring security 3.2.5 to 6.0.1, when I insert tag into spring-security.xml. these spring libraries in my ejb project: 1- spring-aop-6.0.3.jar 2- spring-beans-6.0.3.jar 3- spring-context-6.0.3.jar 4- spring-core-6.0.3.jar 5: spring-expression-6.0.3.jar 6- spring-security-config-6.0.1.jar 7-spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar 8-spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar 9-spring-web-6.0.3.jar 10-spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar 11- spring-security-taglibs-6.0.1.jar 12-spring-security-crypto-6.0.1.jar 13-commons-logging-1.2.jar 14-micrometer-observation-1.10.3.jar

spring-security.xml :

```
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="<http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans>"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd"> 
    <http pattern="/securityNone" security="none"/>
    <http use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <http-basic />
    </http>    
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user name="guest" password="123" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>    
</beans:beans>
```

web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="4.0" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    
    <context-param>                                                                           
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>                                        
        <param-value>                                                                         
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml                                                             
        </param-value>                                                                        
    </context-param>                                                                          
                                                                                          
    <filter>                                                                                  
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>                                  
        <filter-class>
            org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>     
    </filter>                                                                                 
                                                                                          
    <filter-mapping>                                                                          
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>                                  
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>                                                         
    </filter-mapping>
                                                                                          
    <listener>                                                                                
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

I am getting this exceptions:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:377)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:135)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:460)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:191)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1663)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1412)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:915)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:396)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:288)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5005)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:562)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5574)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:510)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:877)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:860)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:644)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2020)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1666)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:82)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:98)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:267)
at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:480)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:199)
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:467)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:516)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:512)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:542)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
at java.base/javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:376)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:533)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1441)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1823)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1699)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:510)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:150)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:440)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:144)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:174)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:153)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:196)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:88)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:246)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:178)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:118)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:96)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:51)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:510)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:82)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:83)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:34)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:101)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:535)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:515)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2736e2e2' of type [org.springframework.security.web.servlet.util.matcher.MvcRequestMatcher] while setting constructor argument
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBeanValue(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:421)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.lambda$resolveValueIfNecessary$1(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:262)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:152)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:686)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:211)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1188)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:561)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:365)
... 68 more

Comment: I am getting this exceptions:  org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring-security.xml] 
                                                                                                                                         Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder

Comment: Do you have spring-security-crypto as dependency in your project?

Comment: Thanks Karthikeyan. I add spring-security-crypto in my project! but know I am getting this exceptions: I am using spring security in ejb                                                                                                                                             org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]

Comment: Show your POM with dependencies. It looks like your are using conflicted dependencies.

Comment: I should not have internet on the operating system, so I have created ant project,I updated the javaee9, I am using Jakarta ee 9 now and these spring libraries in my ejb project:

Comment: 1- spring-aop-6.0.3.jar    2- spring-beans-6.0.3.jar   3- spring-context-6.0.3.jar    4- spring-core-6.0.3.jar   5: spring-expression-6.0.3.jar   6- spring-security-config-6.0.1.jar   7-spring-security-core-6.0.1.jar   8-spring-security-web-6.0.1.jar   9-spring-web-6.0.3.jar    10-spring-webmvc-6.0.3.jar   11- spring-security-taglibs-6.0.1.jar    12-spring-security-crypto-6.0.1.jar   13-commons-logging-1.2.jar    14-micrometer-observation-1.10.3.jar

Comment: According to : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0.0/getting-spring-security.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.